# asp.net - undo delete session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm storing the orders in sessions and i give the possibilty to user to delete the order, but i'm trying to create an "undo" but i don't know how.

When the user ask to delete the session (the order), what you advice me to do to have the possibility to undo it? It don't need to be after X minutes, just in the same page so if he deletes the order, he see an option to undo the action.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the deleted orders in a special "place" in the session, e.g:

```
Session["deleted_orders"] = new List<Order>();
...
```

Or add a `Deleted` flag to the order object.

Comment: Thanks mate, i haven't thought about that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just add another key to the session [OrderDeleted] = true;

Answer (score 0):

If your session state manager is kept in SQL this will be as simple as creating a copy of the session data into an "expired" table. If you keep session in memory, then on delete, create a copy of the session data in a SQL table somewhere along with a timestamp. This allows the record to be destroyed after it has grown moldy enough, but will live long enough that if the undo is clicked, the data you need can be restored.